# Public IP address assigned instead of DHCP ip range address

Tags: router, ip, dhcp

I'm using a second router to connect to my main router to create a new wireless SSID.

Here's my current setup:

First router/main router - Generic branded router is provided by ISP and connected to Internet. LAN IP address is set as 10.x.x.254. We are assigned 5 Public IP addresses: 115.x.x.x. And the WAN ip address for this router is 115.x.x.193.Our DHCP range is set from 10.x.x.200 - 10.x.x.250. If I connect to the SSID from this router, the DHCP works fine.

Second router - Model is Asus RT-n12hp using Wireless Router mode. LAN IP address is set as 10.x.x.253. Router plugged into the ethernet port of first router. DHCP service here is already disabled. But when I connect to this SSID, SOMETIMES I get a local IP address of 115.x.x.x(which is our public IP) instead of 10.x.x.2xx. If I go to the wireless settings, it is showing 115.x.x.193 as the default gateway instead of 10.x.x.254. Why is this so? I have already tried resetting the router to factory settings.

Comment: What mode is the first router set to?  Sounds like you have it configured in 'bridge" mode, which basically, makes your ASUS router the only router on the network.  This is evident by the fact the gateway of the ASUS router is the same as the modem.  Why do you expect your public ip address to be a intranet ip address while connected to the ASUS router anyways?

Comment: Sorry I should rephrase. When connected to the ASUS router, I actually see my LAN IP = Public IP address. I also couldn't see any Modes I'm in.

Comment: *Your question does not indicate that’s the case.*

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Plus, I also checked that the Bridge mode is bound to Port no.4 in the first router. My ASUS router is plugged into Port no. 1 which is PPPoe bound.

Comment: Okay, I tried in my laptop directly into the first router and I also get the public IP. Somehow the DHCP range set in the first router is not working.